# javascript events not working with Chrome Extension , why ! :/

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

HTML  // code

```
input id ="submit_btn" type="submit" value="find" onclick="goto();"
```

Javascript / code

```
 function goto()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("s_keyword").value != "") {
            var url = ("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + document.getElementById("s_keyword").value);
            var site = window.open(url, '_blank');
            site.focus();
        }
    };
```

it never enters into goto function !

Comment: Regarding the duplicate, see "Inline event listeners" in the accepted answer: "*`<button onclick="test();">` **does not work.***"

Answer (score 2):

[Chrome extensions don't support inline events](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution). Add the event listener in your JavaScript, and it'll be fine:

```
document.getElementById('submit_btn').addEventListener('click', goto);
```

You may want to avoid using `goto` as your function's name too. It may be a reserved keyword.

Comment: my javascript code is in external file already ..

Comment: @user3763059 You have some JavaScript in your HTML, which is called inline JavaScript. (Specifically, the `onclick="goto();"` part)